# Set message receive priority for all apps using utlility in common jar

Tags: android, sdk, broadcastreceiver, message

How do I set priority to receive message in different apps which use my common jar library to receive messages?

I have created a module to receive messages with receiver. And now I want to use it in my multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Ordered broadcast

> Ordered broadcasts (sent with `Context.sendOrderedBroadcast`) are
>   delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in
>   turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can
>   completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other
>   receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the
>   `android:priority` attribute of the matching intent-filter; receivers
>   with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html